# Why this h1 not effected by border and margin?

Tags: html, css

Edit:
thanks alot guys i'm glad that i've asked here and got a fast response. now i know there are non-inherited css properties which until now i didn't know about. my brain is saved... .

Excuse me for my basic question, i'm new to coding and need some help.
I've a problem regarding the CSS inheritance rules that i can't really solve.
As far as i have learned rules supposed to be inherited from parents. like when in a `div` i say `color:red` every text within that element will become red.

So why is it when i specify something like a `padding` or `margin` or `border: solid 1px` only
the `div` is effected by it?

example:

```
<pre>

.test {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 5px;
}
</pre>
```

[Resualt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeZWv.jpg)

Why is it that `h1` didnt inherite the `margin` or `border`?

Comment: inheritance works only with specific attributes like `color`, or if you told elements to inherit eg `h1{border: inherit;}`

Comment: thank you i was going crazy with this.

Answer (score 2):

Padding and margin are not inheritted by default.

Comment: i see, i didn't know that . i should google which do or don't then. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of properties that are inherited.  You can also specify that it SHOULD inherit.

Some that ARE inherited by default that I am aware of:

- border-collapse
- border-spacing
- caption-side
- color
- cursor
- direction
- empty-cells
- font-family
- font-size
- font-style
- font-variant
- font-weight
- font-size-adjust
- font-stretch
- font
- letter-spacing
- line-height
- list-style-image
- list-style-position
- list-style-type
- list-style
- orphans
- quotes
- tab-size
- text-align
- text-align-last
- text-decoration-color
- text-indent
- text-justify
- text-shadow
- text-transform
- visibility
- white-space
- widows
- word-break
- word-spacing
- word-wrap

Here we tell it to inherit a border

```css
p {
  border: medium solid;
}

p.inherit-me em {
  border: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>Here I am, I am greater than great</p>

<p>Here I am, I am <em>greater</em> than great</p>

<p class="inherit-me">Here I am forced, I am <em>greater</em> than great</p>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance